# In console I see "undefined" instead of 25. Why? How to see the correct result?

Tags: javascript, function, call

```js
function Square(a) {
  this.a = a ** 2;
  return a;
}

const value = Square.call({}, 5);
console.log(value.a);
```

Actual -> value.a = undefined

Expected -> value.a = 25

Comment: Your code is all over the place to put it nicely. What is Sqr? Where is it defined? You reference this .call function but the first param is just an empty Object, but the function Square only takes one input? Extremely confused by what you're doing

Comment: `value` will just be the number input you send to the method. You need to `return this` instead of `return a` if you want get the object passed to `call` method

Comment: ```
function Square(a)
{
 return a ** 2;
}

vall = Square.call(this, 5);
console.log(vall);
```
how is your code getting access to this.a ? 
Try this instead!

Comment: Thank you @adiga for pointing it out. It was my bad :P

Comment: Other users have already replied to you. Now, my curiosity is, why aren't you using `new`?

Comment: Great question @CristianTraìna.. I wanted to evaluate call method usage and thus took this approach.

It can also be done like this:


**const value = new Square(5);**

Comment: Yes, the difference is that using `new` you would end up with a `square` object. Then you should do: `const square = new Square(5); const value = square.a`

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `a`, so `5`, not the object. And you pass an object `{}` for `this`, but it is not stored anywhere, you can't check it later. If you passed an object which you have access to afterwards, like `diz` below, its `.a` becomes 25 properly:

```js
function Square(a) {
  this.a = a ** 2;
  return a;
}

const diz = {};
const value = Square.call(diz, 5);
console.log("Returned 'a', should be 5:",value);
console.log("Altered 'object.a', should be 25:",diz.a);
```

Alternatively you might have wanted to `return this;`:

```js
function Square(a) {
  this.a = a ** 2;
  return this;
}

const value = Square.call({}, 5);
console.log(value.a);
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why you use `this`, or where this object `value` is coming from. But let me explain. Your argument `a` can't be changed directly. You need to assign it to a variable, e.g. `result` to change and return it.

```
return result = a ** 2;
```

To call the function, you don't use `.call`. You simply call it in your `console.log()`.

```
console.log(square(a));
```

The whole magic of this function you want to write:

```
function square(a) {
    return result = a * a;
}

console.log(square(a));

// expected result is 25
```

I recommend a course on freeCodeCamp to learn the fundamentals of JavaScript. You can find it [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/).

Comment: ** stands for exponent and thus is not the same as multiplication operator *
Also, I wrote this piece of code just to evaluate the call method. Please refer to the answer from @adiga, in the comments section.

Comment: Ok... I get it. Then I guess the answer by tevemadar is the correct one.